# python driver must be manually updated

Tags: python, drivers

I have written a function for a driver in python. Works good.

But...if i start my blend file, i first have to run one time my python script and then update all drivers in order to make them work.

Is there a "hack" or workaround so that the drivers are "ready working" when starting the blend file?

my python script:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context


def getStepWidth():
    

    stepWidth = 5 * 5
    return stepWidth
    

bpy.app.driver_namespace["getStepWidth"] = getStepWidth
```

Comment: Have you tried loading your startup.blend, running the script and then saving the startup again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy. Click on Text → Register:

[image]

In older versions .py extension in block name were required, but it worked without it when I was testing it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure `Auto Run python scripts` and save preferences

[image]

2. Put the function to addon and install it (need save preferences)

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "My Addon",
    "author": "me",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D",
    "description": "hello",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy

def getStepWidth(): return 5 * 5

def update_driver(obj):
    try:
        for fc in obj.animation_data.drivers:
            fc.driver.expression = fc.driver.expression
    except:
        pass

@ bpy.app.handlers.persistent
def run_when_load_file(dummy):
    print("run_when_load_file")
    bpy.app.driver_namespace["getStepWidth"] = getStepWidth

    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        update_driver(obj)


def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(run_when_load_file)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.remove(run_when_load_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

3. Open the blender file, it will update all driver for all object